# How to edit only few fields and disable other fields on my form on MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am making a inventory tracking tool and in this tool we can book the devices for the testers. But I am having a problem that when I try to edit one of the booking all fields are open for editing and I don't want that. Only fields that should be editable will be ActualCheckIn and ActualCheckOut but I am lost on how I am suppose to do that. If you guys can help me it would be very helpful. I have post the code for my bookingController.cs.

```
       public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
           var bookings =
              await
                _db.Bookings.Include(b => b.Tester)
                    .Include(b => b.Inventory)
                    .Include(b => b.Inventory.Device)
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .ToListAsync();

        return View(bookings);
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> AddBooking()
    {
        var viewModel = new BookingViewModel
        {
            BookingDate = DateTime.Now,
            Testers = await _db.Testers.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync(),
            Inventories = GetAvailableInventories()
        };

        return View("Booking", viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> AddBooking(BookingViewModel model)
    {
        if (model.Action.Equals("cancel"))
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            model.Testers = await _db.Testers.ToListAsync();
            model.Inventories = GetAvailableInventories();
            return View("Booking", model);
        }

        var booking = new Booking
        {
            BookingId = model.BookingId,
            BookingDate = model.BookingDate,
            TesterId = model.TesterId,
            LabNumber = model.LabNumber.Value,
            PlanCheckIn = model.PlanCheckIn.Value,
            PlanCheckOut = model.PlanCheckOut,
            ActualCheckIn = model.ActualCheckIn,
            ActualCheckOut = model.ActualCheckOut,
            Notes = model.Notes,
            TotalHours = model.TotalHours
        };

        using (var transaction = _db.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                // update device usage if new booking
                if (booking.BookingId == 0)
                {
                    var invetory = await _db.Inventories.FindAsync(model.LabNumber.Value);
                    var device = await _db.Devices.FindAsync(invetory.DeviceId);
                    device.TotalUsage++;
                }

                _db.Bookings.AddOrUpdate(booking);
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> EditBooking(int bookingId)
    {
        var booking = await _db.Bookings.FindAsync(bookingId);

        var model = new BookingViewModel
        {
            BookingId = booking.BookingId,
            BookingDate = booking.BookingDate,
            TesterId = booking.TesterId,
            LabNumber = booking.LabNumber,
            PlanCheckOut = booking.PlanCheckOut,
            PlanCheckIn = booking.PlanCheckIn,
            ActualCheckIn = booking.ActualCheckIn,
            ActualCheckOut = booking.ActualCheckOut,
            Notes = booking.Notes,
            TotalHours = booking.TotalHours,
            Testers = await _db.Testers.ToListAsync(),
            Inventories = GetAvailableInventories(booking.LabNumber)
        };


        return View("Edit", model);
    }
```

I also have another question that if all fields in my form is filled, is there any way that I can disable the link for editing that booking? Thanks in advance!!

Here is my view.cshtml:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
     <div class="form-group">
         @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ActualCheckIn, "Actual CheckOut", new { @class = "col-sm-3 control-label" })
         <div class="col-sm-9">
              <div class="input-group date">
                   <div class="input-group-addon">
                         <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                   </div>
                   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ActualCheckIn, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control pull-right datepicker", id = "actualCheckInInput" })
               </div>

         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ActualCheckOut, "Actual CheckIn", new { @class = "col-sm-3 control-label" })
         <div class="col-sm-9">
             <div class="input-group date">
                 <div class="input-group-addon">
                     <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                 </div>
                 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ActualCheckOut, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control pull-right datepicker", id = "actualCheckOutInput" })
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Nothing in your code has anything to do with that is/isn't editable. You would need to show your view (also, that is what you would be changing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the cleanest way would be to introduce a different ViewModel for the Edit usecase that only exposes the properties that can be edited. This increases flexibility and maintainability.

```
public class EditBookingViewModel {

    // post as hidden field so we can fetch the record to update
    public long BookingId {get; set;} 

    // render inputs for these fields so they can be edited
    public DateTime ActualCheckIn  {get; set;}
    public DateTime ActualCheckOut {get; set;}
}
```

As an alternative, reuse the BookingViewModel. The key is to only render an `<input>` for the properties that can be edited:

Edit.cshtml

```
@model BookingViewModel

@{ Html.BeginForm("EditBooking", "Booking", FormMethod.Post) }

@* Shown, editable, posted back *@
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ActualCheckIn)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ActualCheckOut)

@* Shown, not editable, not posted back *@
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.BookingDate)

@* Not shown, not editable, posted back *@
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.BookingId)

@{ Html.EndForm(); }
```

In the POST EditBooking action, retrieve the booking to be updated from the DB using the ID, and only map the editable fields

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> EditBooking(BookingViewModel postData) {
    var existingBooking = await _db.Bookings.FindAsync(postData.BookingId);
    existingBooking.ActualCheckIn  = postData.ActualCheckIn;
    // ...
}
```